# Render Bbcode in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, render

I would like to find a component, possibility, to render some basic BBcode with JavaFX.

My need is to allow a user to type some small texts like that :

```
Hello [b] every body [i], my name is[/i] Superman [color=red] ! [color][b]
```

I initially thought I could do that with the TextFlow component. But if the user is imbricating a lot of styles, I would end up applying a Style for every letter!

I then thought about using a WebView but since I should be able to show this "texts" inside some cell in a TableView, I cannot afford to instantiate 50 WebView for displaying 50 styled texts..

I've heard about RichTextFX or Markdown Writer FX but I don't know if these will suits my needs.
Thank you for any advice!

Comment: bbcode is ultimately text which PHP converts to HTML, right? Why don't you use some PHP mill to render the HTML and then use that instead?

Comment: I said Bbcode but it could be anything else.. I don't want HTML because I would need to instantiate a WebView for each TableCell in my tableView and that would be overkill..